# Is there a way to add Category column to admin Product Grid?

Tags: product, admin, attributes, magento-1.8, grid

I am trying to add a column to a module that will shows products and the related category. I have been able to show the product names etc put I am not able to get the category name to show in the grid.

Grid.php

```
<?php

class Custom_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Export_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId('productGrid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->setVarNameFilter('product_filter');

    }

    protected function _getStore()
    {
        $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        return Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('category_ids')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
            $collection->joinField('qty',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left');
        }
        if ($store->getId()) {
            //$collection->setStoreId($store->getId());
            $adminStore = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
            $collection->addStoreFilter($store);
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'name',
                'catalog_product/name',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $adminStore
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'custom_name',
                'catalog_product/name',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'status',
                'catalog_product/status',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'visibility',
                'catalog_product/visibility',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $store->getId()
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'price',
                'catalog_product/price',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'left',
                $store->getId()
            );
        }
        else {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
            $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
            $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
        }


        $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        $this->getCollection()->addWebsiteNamesToResult();
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _addColumnFilterToCollection($column)
    {
        if ($this->getCollection()) {
            if ($column->getId() == 'websites') {
                $this->getCollection()->joinField('websites',
                    'catalog/product_website',
                    'website_id',
                    'product_id=entity_id',
                    null,
                    'left');
            }
        }
        return parent::_addColumnFilterToCollection($column);
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {


        $this->addColumn('entity_id',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('ID'),
                'width' => '50px',
                'type'  => 'number',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
            ));
        $this->addColumn('name',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name'),
                'index' => 'name',
            ));

        $store = $this->_getStore();
        if ($store->getId()) {
            $this->addColumn('custom_name',
                array(
                    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name in %s', $store->getName()),
                    'index' => 'custom_name',
                ));
        }

        $this->addColumn( 'categories',
            array(
                'header' => Mage::helper( 'catalog' )->__( 'Categories' ),
                'width' => '100px',
                'sortable' => true,
                'index' => 'categories',
                'sort_index' => 'category',
                'filter_index' => 'category'
            ));

        $this->addColumn('type',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Type'),
                'width' => '60px',
                'index' => 'type_id',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'options' => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type')->getOptionArray(),
            ));

        $sets = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_set_collection')
            ->setEntityTypeFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId())
            ->load()
            ->toOptionHash();

        $this->addColumn('set_name',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Attrib. Set Name'),
                'width' => '100px',
                'index' => 'attribute_set_id',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'options' => $sets,
            ));

        $this->addColumn('sku',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('SKU'),
                'width' => '80px',
                'index' => 'sku',
            ));

        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $this->addColumn('price',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Price'),
                'type'  => 'price',
                'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                'index' => 'price',
            ));

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
            $this->addColumn('qty',
                array(
                    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Qty'),
                    'width' => '100px',
                    'type'  => 'number',
                    'index' => 'qty',
                ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('visibility',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Visibility'),
                'width' => '70px',
                'index' => 'visibility',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'options' => Mage::getModel('catalog/product_visibility')->getOptionArray(),
            ));

        $this->addColumn('status',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Status'),
                'width' => '70px',
                'index' => 'status',
                'type'  => 'options',
                'options' => Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->getOptionArray(),
            ));

        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('websites',
                array(
                    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Websites'),
                    'width' => '100px',
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'index'     => 'websites',
                    'type'      => 'options',
                    'options'   => Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()->toOptionHash(),
                ));
        }

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Rss')) {
            $this->addRssList('rss/catalog/notifystock', Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Notify Low Stock RSS'));
        }

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel'));

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure if I need to add a Table Join or Join Attribute and would welcome any assistance please!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to create an extension to display category in product grid. Please create following files and it will work for you:

Create a new file on `app/code/local/SoftProdigy/AdminGridCategoryFilter/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid/Render/Category.php` location and add following code:

```
<?php
class SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid_Render_Category extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($row->getEntityId());
        $cats = $product->getCategoryIds();
        $allCats = '';
        foreach($cats as $key => $cat)
        {
            $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat);
            $allCats.= $_category->getName();
            if($key < count($cats)-1)
                $allCats.= ',<br />';
        }
        return $allCats;
    }

}
```

Create a new file on `app/code/local/SoftProdigy/AdminGridCategoryFilter/etc/config.xml` location and add following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter>
            <version>0.0.0.1</version>
        </SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <admingridcategoryfilter>
                <class>SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter_Model</class>
            </admingridcategoryfilter>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <admingridcategoryfilter>
                <class>SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter_Helper</class>
            </admingridcategoryfilter>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <admingridcategoryfilter>
                <class>SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter_Block</class>
            </admingridcategoryfilter>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                <observers>
                    <admingridcategoryfilter>
                        <class>admingridcategoryfilter/observer</class>
                        <method>addCategoryFilterToProductGrid</method>
                    </admingridcategoryfilter>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Create a new file on `app/code/local/SoftProdigy/AdminGridCategoryFilter/Helper/Data.php` location and add following code:

```
<?php
class SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Create a new file on `app/code/local/SoftProdigy/AdminGridCategoryFilter/Model/Observer.php` location and add following code:

```
<?php
class SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter_Model_Observer
{

    public function addCategoryFilterToProductGrid(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {   
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        if( ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid)  ) {
            $block->addColumnAfter('softprodigy_category_list', array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('admingridcategoryfilter')->__('Category'),
                    'index'     => 'softprodigy_category_list',
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'width' => '250px',
                    'type'  => 'options',
                    'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('admingridcategoryfilter/system_config_source_category')->toOptionArray(),
                    'renderer'  => 'admingridcategoryfilter/catalog_product_grid_render_category',
                    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, 'filterCallback'),
            ),'name');
        }
    }

    public function filterCallback($collection, $column)
    {
        $value = $column->getFilter()->getValue();
        $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($value);
        $collection->addCategoryFilter($_category);

        return $collection;
    }

}
```

Create a new file on `app/code/local/SoftProdigy/AdminGridCategoryFilter/Model/System/Config/Source/Category.php` location and add following code:

```
<?php
class SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter_Model_System_Config_Source_Category
{
    public function toOptionArray($addEmpty = true)
    {
        $options = array();
        foreach ($this->load_tree() as $category) {
            $options[$category['value']] =  $category['label'];
        }

        return $options;
    }



    public function buildCategoriesMultiselectValues(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $node, $values, $level = 0)
    {
        $level++;

        $values[$node->getId()]['value'] =  $node->getId();
        $values[$node->getId()]['label'] = str_repeat("--", $level) . $node->getName();

        foreach ($node->getChildren() as $child)
        {
            $values = $this->buildCategoriesMultiselectValues($child, $values, $level);
        }

        return $values;
    }

    public function load_tree()
    {
        $store = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        $parentId = $store ? Mage::app()->getStore($store)->getRootCategoryId() : 1;  // Current store root category

        $tree = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/category_tree')->load();

        $root = $tree->getNodeById($parentId);

        if($root && $root->getId() == 1)
        {
            $root->setName(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Root'));
        }

        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
        ->setStoreId($store)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('is_active');

        $tree->addCollectionData($collection, true);

        return $this->buildCategoriesMultiselectValues($root, array());
    }
}
```

Create a new file on `app/etc/modules/SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter.xml` location and add following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
                <Mage_Adminhtml />
            </depends>
        </SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Now clear cache from cache management and you can see category column in product grid.

Comment: I have implemented your code and I can see the categories but they are showing in every column!!

Comment: With the above code a separate category column will be display.

Comment: I had already created a module which diplayed the products in a Grid but I needed the categories so added your code but I was getting the categories in all my columns...

Comment: It is correct to have the module created under the local code branch as its a local customisation - community is is for extensions which will be made publicly available. As such the class files should be created under `app/code/local/` as opposed to changing the `codePool` to community.

Comment: Very good ! works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Minor update,

in the:
app/code/local/SoftProdigy/AdminGridCategoryFilter/etc/config.xml

needs to actually be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
<default>
<modules>
        <SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter>
            <version>0.0.0.1</version>
        </SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <admingridcategoryfilter>
                <class>SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter_Model</class>
            </admingridcategoryfilter>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <admingridcategoryfilter>
                <class>SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter_Helper</class>
            </admingridcategoryfilter>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <admingridcategoryfilter>
                <class>SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter_Block</class>
            </admingridcategoryfilter>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                <observers>
                    <admingridcategoryfilter>
                        <class>admingridcategoryfilter/observer</class>
                        <method>addCategoryFilterToProductGrid</method>
                    </admingridcategoryfilter>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</default>
</setup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done all the steps according to SoftProdigy answer, but nothing happend.

Should I add something in grid.php or call any function to make it works?

A while after this post i found the problem:
in
app/etc/modules/SoftProdigy_AdminGridCategoryFilter.xml

shoud be `<codePool>community</codePool>`