# Inventory Management grid customization

Tags: magento-1.9, inventory, product-grid

I'm working on Inventory Management Module.I want to add three new columns in grid.I was able to add new columns.That's fine.But now i am not able to populate data in respective columns.Please refer below screen :[image]

I have added three columns color,shelf locations and combinations.I created these attributes and imported data.Please help me out guys to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to have a look on some same questions on stackoverflow?

[Add attribute column to admin product grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/56194/add-attribute-column-to-admin-product-grid)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990910/add-column-to-magento-admin-catolog-manage-products

Or even better: https://magento.stackexchange.com/search?q=populate+data+in+column

Comment: Problem solved.I have already added columns.We have to add attributes to attribute set.That's it.Thanks bro.

Comment: Only problem is color column.Showing number 3 instead of colour.Color attribute type is dropdown.

Comment: Changed attribute tyoe dropdown to text field.