# Magento2.4.5: How to add custom column in catalog categories product grid?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

I have added a custom column in the product grid and that column has a **data-source**

and I want to add that same column in **catalog > categories > Products in Category**
[image]

in this grid i want to add a custom column, is it possible?
**any idea, Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rewrite below class and add your column to it.

To override this class `Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product` use below code in di.xml file

`app/code/vendorename/modulename/etc/adminhtml/di.xml` add below code to it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product" type="Vendorename\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product" />
</config>
```

Create new class `Vendorename\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tab\Product`
add below code to _prepareColumns function add new column to grid

```
/**
     * @return Extended
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        if (!$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()) {
            $this->addColumn(
                'in_category',
                [
                    'type' => 'checkbox',
                    'name' => 'in_category',
                    'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                    'index' => 'entity_id',
                    'header_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction',
                    'column_css_class' => 'col-select col-massaction'
                ]
            );
        }
        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn('name', ['header' => __('Name'), 'index' => 'name']);
        $this->addColumn('sku', ['header' => __('SKU'), 'index' => 'sku']);
        $this->addColumn(
            'visibility',
            [
                'header' => __('Visibility'),
                'index' => 'visibility',
                'type' => 'options',
                'options' => $this->visibility->getOptionArray(),
                'header_css_class' => 'col-visibility',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-visibility'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'status',
            [
                'header' => __('Status'),
                'index' => 'status',
                'type' => 'options',
                'options' => $this->status->getOptionArray()
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'type' => 'currency',
                'currency_code' => (string)$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                    \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                ),
                'index' => 'price'
            ]
        );

        //add your custom column
        $this->addColumn(
            'test',
            [
                'header' => __('Test'),
                'type' => 'currency',
                'currency_code' => (string)$this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                    \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency::XML_PATH_CURRENCY_BASE,
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                ),
                'index' => 'price'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'position',
            [
                'header' => __('Position'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'position',
                'editable' => !$this->getCategory()->getProductsReadonly()
            ]
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow:

[Is there a way to add Category column to admin Product Grid?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/is-there-a-way-to-add-category-column-to-admin-product-grid)

I don't know if the above instructions are right for you, but I think it will help you

Comment: This code is from magento1, needs a updated answers